# How to get the current user in ModelFormMixin post() method?

Tags: django, django-views

How do i get the currently logged in user in the following implementation of the LIstview and ModelFormMixin:

```
class ListMessages(ListView, ModelFormMixin):
model = Message
template_name = 'accounts/list_messages.html'
context_object_name = 'messages'
form_class = MessageHiddenUserForm
#success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:list_messages', kwargs={'uname': })

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    self.form = self.get_form(self.form_class)

    if self.form.is_valid():
        self.form.user_to = self.kwargs['uname']
        self.form.user_from = request.user #this doesn't work
        self.object = self.form.save()

    return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not where you get the user from, but where you assign it to. Setting arbitrary attributes on a form doesn't do anything at all; you need to assign it to the result of `form.save`.

```
obj = self.form.save(commit=False)
obj.user_to = self.kwargs['uname']
obj.user_from = request.user
obj.save()
```

Note, you must not call `self.get()` directly like that; you must *always* redirect after a successful post.

```
return redirect('accounts:list_messages', kwargs={...})
```

Comment: Helped me solve my problem. However, the obj.user_to required a User instance so I did `obj.user_to = User.objects.get(username=self.kwargs['uname'])`

Answer (score 0):

For method "post" use request.user.username to get current logged-in user.